# Changing a JButton text when clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have created a class which extends JDialog, where I have some checkboxes and 3 buttons: accept, cancel, and select all.

When user clicks select all, every checkbox should get checked, and if clicked again, every checkbox should get unchecked. That's working fine, but i also want the text of the button to change between "select all" and "unselect all". I'm having troubles there, so when user clicks the button and text changes to "unselect all", the button dissapears.

I have reduced the class to its simplest form here:

```
    public class NodeSelectionCheckBoxJDialog extends JDialog {
    public enum Options {ACEPT, CANCEL};
    private Options selectedOption;
    private JButton allButton;
    private boolean allCheckBoxesSelected;
    private JButton aceptButton;

    public NodeSelectionCheckBoxJDialog(){
        super(MainFrame.getInstance());
        this.setTitle("Select nodes to apply");
        this.setModal(true);

        selectedOption = Options.CANCEL;
        nodeCheckBoxesSet = new HashSet<NodeCheckBox>();

        try {
            initComponents();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void initComponents() throws Exception {
        this.getContentPane().add(createActionButtons(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private Component createActionButtons() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
        allCheckBoxesSelected = false;
        aceptButton = new JButton("Accept");
        aceptButton.setEnabled(false);
        buttonsPanel.add(aceptButton);
        aceptButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selectedOption = Options.ACEPT;
                dispose();
            }
        });

        JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
        buttonsPanel.add(cancelButton);
        cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                selectedOption = Options.CANCEL;
                dispose();
            }
        });

        allButton = new JButton("Select all");
        buttonsPanel.add(allButton);
        allButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(allCheckBoxesSelected){
                    allCheckBoxesSelected = false;
                    allButton.setText("Select all");
                } else {
                    allCheckBoxesSelected = true;
                    allButton.setText("Unselect all");
                }
            }
        });

        return buttonsPanel;
    }
}
```

I can't see what's wrong. Any help?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code? How are you selecting/deselecting the checkboxes? Are you manipulating the `allButton` variable somewhere else?

Comment: I have a listener for the checkboxes, but i erased it to make the code simpler. The selection/deselection works fine, the problem appears only if I also try to change the button text. And no, allButton is not being manipulated elsewhere

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The button does not disappear, it just becomes too wide to fit in the window. Just redraw the component when changing the button label :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(allCheckBoxesSelected){
        allCheckBoxesSelected = false;
        allButton.setText("Select all");
    } else {
        allCheckBoxesSelected = true;
        allButton.setText("Unselect all");
        NodeSelectionCheckBoxJDialog.this.pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

event.getSource() to access the clicked button

Comment: It is equivalent to the way I'm approaching it. Compiles, but problem stays and button dissapear.

Answer (score 2):

another way is use ButtonModel that implemeted interesting methods for example

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.AbstractBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class TextAreaInButton {

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("sssssssss");
    private JButton tip1Null = new JButton(" test button ");

    public TextAreaInButton() {
        Border line, raisedbevel, loweredbevel, title, empty;
        line = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
        raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("");
        empty = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(1, 1, 1, 1);
        final Border compound;
        Color crl = (Color.blue);
        compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty, new OldRoundedBorderLine(crl));
        Color crl1 = (Color.red);
        final Border compound1;
        compound1 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty, new OldRoundedBorderLine(crl1));
        Color crl2 = (Color.black);
        final Border compound2;
        compound2 = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(empty, new OldRoundedBorderLine(crl2));
        tip1Null.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        tip1Null.setForeground(Color.darkGray);
        tip1Null.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 30));
        tip1Null.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        tip1Null.setBorderPainted(true);
        tip1Null.setFocusPainted(false);
        tip1Null.setBorder(compound);
        tip1Null.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        tip1Null.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);

        tip1Null.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
                if (model.isRollover()) {
                    tip1Null.setBorder(compound1);
                } else {
                    tip1Null.setBorder(compound);
                }
                if (model.isPressed()) {
                    tip1Null.setBorder(compound2);
                    String btnText = (tip1Null.getText());
                    if (btnText.equals("Selected")) {
                        tip1Null.setText("Un_Selected");
                    } else {
                        tip1Null.setText("Selected");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(tip1Null, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setLocation(150, 150);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(310, 75));
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextAreaInButton taib = new TextAreaInButton();
            }
        });
    }
}

class OldRoundedBorderLine extends AbstractBorder {

    private final static int MARGIN = 5;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Color color;

    OldRoundedBorderLine(Color clr) {
        color = clr;
    }

    public void setColor(Color clr) {
        color = clr;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, MARGIN, MARGIN);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c) {
        return new Insets(MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN, MARGIN);
    }

    @Override
    public Insets getBorderInsets(Component c, Insets insets) {
        insets.left = MARGIN;
        insets.top = MARGIN;
        insets.right = MARGIN;
        insets.bottom = MARGIN;
        return insets;
    }
}
```